# Split View - Rotated XIB clips content

Tags: ipad, interface-builder, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm working with a split view iPad app for the first time. I have my Detail View all laid out on Interface Builder (in portrait mode, mind you) and all the IBOutlets and things are connected and all code is working just fine. However, I have a `UILabel` in the bottom left of the screen and when I rotate from portrait to landscape, the label seems to get cut off.

How can I avoid content clipping when rotating the device in a split-view iPad app?

(edit) **Visuals:**

Portrait View:

[image: Portrait View]

Landscape View:

[image: Landscape View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than clipping, this might have more to do with the resizing masks on the label. When done using IB, they are fixed to top and left. So they maintain the distance to the top which is the reason the label has gone off screen when the height reduced. You will have to set it fixed to bottom and left or whatever is suitable based on your layout requirements.

[image]